# how to connect my docker container (frontend) connect to a containerized database running on a different VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Unable to connect to containers running on separate docker hosts

I've got 2 docker Tomcat containers running on 2 different Ubuntu vm's. System-A has a webservice running and System-B has a db. I haven't been able to figure out how to connect the application running on system-A to the db running on system-B. When I run the database on system-A, the application(which is also running on system-A) can connect to the database. I'm using docker-compose to setup the network(which works fine when both containers are running on the same VM). I've execd into etc/hosts file in the application container on system-A and I think whats missing is the ip address of System-B.

```
services:
  db:
    image: mydb
    hostname: mydbName
    ports:
      - "8012: 8012"
    networks:
     data:
       aliases:
        - mydbName
   api:
     image: myApi
     hostname: myApiName
     ports:
        - "8810: 8810"
     networks:
       data:
networks:
  data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would configure this exactly the same way you would as if Docker wasn't involved: configure the Tomcat instance with the DNS name or IP address of the other server.  You would need to make sure the service is published outside of Docker space using a `ports:` directive.

On `server-a.example.com` you could run this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: myApi
    ports:
      - "8810:8810"
    env:
      DATABASE_URL: "http://server-b.example.com:8012"
```

And on `server-b.example.com`:

```
version: '3'
services:
db:
  image: mydb
  ports:
    - "8012:8012"
```

In principle it would be possible to set up an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) connecting the two hosts, but this is a significantly more complicated setup.

(You definitely don't want to use `docker exec` to modify `/etc/hosts` in a container: you'll have to repeat this step every time you delete and recreate the container, and manually maintaining hosts files is tedious and error-prone, particularly if you're moving containers between hosts.  [Consul](https://consul.io/) could work as a service-discovery system that provides a DNS service.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had done that but was missing something(after which I tried the other approaches mentioned thinking it was too simple). your answer confirmed my initial hunch. looked around and found that the configuration file was coming from a the base container. fixed that and its all good now. cheers